# How to add value to upload_tmp_dir, and i cannot access php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

How to add value to upload_tmp_dir, and i cannot access php.ini file, i even tried using htaccess for changing values such as

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M,
```

but ended up getting 500 error and my configuration file is located in `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini`  and I cannot access it,
,Upload options was working fine when I run it on localhost but when I hosted it , Uploaded operations fails,please help.
I cannot use upload options due to this error

> PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in
>   Unknown on line 0,

Thankyou

Comment: Please provide details about the OS on which you have hosted your script. And also please make sure that you have given enough permission to read and write file for that particular folder.

Comment: Im using Linux cpanel hosting, and the permission for upload folder is 777

Comment: The upload_tmp_dir can be configured inside php.ini or the httpd.conf(if using Apache). You can write <Directory /path/to/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /tmp
</Directory> inside httpd.conf depending upon your hosting settings.

Comment: how can i use httpdocs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom php.ini file and place it in your root folder. You new settings will be effective. I found this article helpful [How to use custom php.ini files on shared hosting](https://websistent.com/using-custom-php-ini-files-on-shared-hosting/)